# How to control the flow of tasks within SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have a series of 5 tasks, and would like guidance on how to run them in a specified order:

[image]

The order that I need:

1. Run the entire series.
2. And then only run these:[image]

I checked out [this](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2009/container-tasks-ssis/) and [this](http://sql-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/ssis-containers.html) resource, but am not sure how to apply them.

Comment: Run all 5, then loop back around and do the first 3 again?

Comment: I'm asking, is your request that you'd like to run all the steps in the package and then go back and re-run the first three?

Comment: If you are attempting to do things this way. You may be building a a solution that's dare I say. Not good.

Comment: Put them in a sequence container, and add a loop condition?

Comment: @Siyual cool! can you give me an example?

Comment: @Zane you are probably right in textbook terms, but in the real world we have limited resources and perfection is not a goal

Comment: What is the loop criteria, when do you want it to re-run the first 3 and when do you not want it to?  If they're always getting re-run after the first 5 steps, just make them steps 6,7, and 8.

Comment: Seems like you could just add those same 3 tasks at the end?

Comment: @GoatCO its not really a loop, it's just run steps: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Then it's as simple as copying them as steps 6,7, and 8.

Comment: @Lamak yes i definitely can, but it would be a tremendous amount of overhead. the first step is a ton of data flow components http://screencast.com/t/bRyyYfW2AYK

Comment: It's an SSIS package, it would only execute them in order, so unless you have like a 1GB dtsx file, you're fine to just copy pasta.

Comment: But.....you need to run them again, why would it be an overhead then?

Comment: @GoatCO indeed thats the question, instead of copying them as separate tasks, how do i just rerun them after the series is done

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put all those tasks inside a For Loop Container. The iterations would be controlled by a simple Counter variable and limited for values 1 to 2.

Then for the last two tasks, I would set the Disable property using an expression, e.g.

`@[User::Counter] == 2`